# Jframe not adding ImageIcon from Jlabel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, imageicon

I lost a bet and had to make a terrible, but simple, java program that basically is supposed to just add .png images on top of one another in a JFrame.

```
private ImageIcon base;
private ImageIcon type;
private ImageIcon color;
private ImageIcon shine;
private JLabel base5;
private JLabel type5;
private JLabel color5;
private JLabel shine5; 
public Thing()
{

}
public Thing(ImageIcon base,ImageIcon type,ImageIcon color,ImageIcon shine)
{
    base=base;
    type=type;
    color=color;
    shine=shine;
}
public static void drawThing()
{
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
ImageIcon base = null,type=null,color=null,shine=null;



    String base1 = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose A Base");
    if(base1.equalsIgnoreCase("base"))
    {
        base=new ImageIcon("base.png");
    }
    String type1 = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose type of hat”);
    if(type1.equalsIgnoreCase(“top”))
    {
        String type2 = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose A Color(blue/green/red/pink");
        if(type2.equalsIgnoreCase("red"))
                {
                    type=new ImageIcon("top_hat_neon_red.png");
                }
        if(type2.equalsIgnoreCase("blue"))
                {
                    type=new ImageIcon("top_hat_neon_blue.png");
                }
        if(type2.equalsIgnoreCase("green"))
                {
                    type=new ImageIcon("top_hat_neon_green.png");
                }
        if(type2.equalsIgnoreCase("pink"))
                {
                    type=new ImageIcon("top_hat_pink.png");
                }

    }
    String shine1 = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Do you want it to be shiny?(yes/no)");
    if(shine1.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
    {
            shine=new ImageIcon("shine.png");
        }
    if(shine1.equalsIgnoreCase(“no”))
        {
            shine=null;
        }

    Thing thing=new Thing(base,type,color,shine);


    frame.setSize(500, 700);
    JLabel base5 = new JLabel(base);
    JLabelcolor5 = new JLabel(color);
    JLabel shine5 = new JLabel(shine);





    frame.add(base5);
    frame.add(color5);
    frame.add(shine5);
    /**/

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

The Problem I'm having is the JFrame will open after choosing everything, and be completely blank
All the images are loaded in a resources folder inside the src folder
the main is in the tester class and it only creates a Thing and then runs the drawThing() method
I'm a novice at this so I'm more than likely missing something obvious.
 (I am never doing a bet like this again)

Comment: Your program ignores the fact that a JFrame's contentPane (the container that holds the components added to a JFrame) uses BorderLayout, and so that any component added will cover up and replace all components added previously. Consider using a different layout manager. Also, I recommend that you create a small test program that shows a single image within a JOptionPane, to make sure that you're reading the images in correctly. Also, I recommend that you get rid of all references to a "bet" as it makes your question look as if you're trying to avoid telling us that its homework. Looks foolish.

Comment: (offtopic) also, indent and format your code properly, you have an error with your quotation, like the `“top”` that should be `"top"` (use the neutral quotation, not the left and right one)...

Comment: Also, `JLabel color5 = new JLabel(color);` should probably be `JLabel color5 = new JLabel(type);` (color is always null)

Comment: *"..I'm a novice at this so I'm more than likely missing something obvious."*  Yep.  Since this is a Q&A Site, the obvious thing to do is to ask a question.  *What is your question?*